# MySQL multiple left join issues

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables that I am trying to query, and I can only get about half the information I need. The two tables are:

client_skills_new:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | client_id | job_sector | job_type | job_name    |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 79 | 24        | 3          | 39       | Accountant  |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 80 | 25        | 3          | 115      | Broker      |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 81 | 24        | 5          | 241      | Shop Worker |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

and

job_sectors:

```
+-----+--------------------------+---------------+
| id  | name                     | job_sector_id |
+-----+--------------------------+---------------+
| 3   | Accounting & Finance     | 0             |
+-----+--------------------------+---------------+
| 115 | Brokerage                | 3             |
+-----+--------------------------+---------------+
| 22  | Sales & Retail           | 0             |
+-----+--------------------------+---------------+
```

The job sectors table actually contains job sectors and job types in one column (name). job_sector id links the two (ie brokerage is a subheading of accounting and finance - job_sector_id = id).

In the client_skills_new table the numbers stored under job_sector and job_type relate to the id column of job_sectors. What I am trying to do is write a query which will join the two to give me the textual value in the job_sectors table related to the job_sector and job_type integers in client_skills_new.

So far I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT client_skills_new.job_sector, job_sectors.id, job_sectors.name 
FROM job_sectors
LEFT JOIN client_skills_new 
ON client_skills_new.job_sector = job_sectors.id
WHERE client_id='$client_id';
```

From this, I get results as follows:

```
+------------+----+--------------------------+
| job_sector | id | name                     |
+------------+----+--------------------------+
| 3          | 3  | Accounting & Finance     |
+------------+----+--------------------------+
| 22         | 22 | Sales & Retail           |
+------------+----+--------------------------+
```

Which given id of 24 from my top table gives me about half of what I need. I'd like the query to also include the text name corresponding to job_type. I'm not quite sure what I need to add to finish the query. I tried a second left join but this kept erroring.

The output I'm looking for, given each id in client_skills_new, is as follows:

```
+----+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| id | job_sector               | job_type  | job_name |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 80 | Accounting & Finance     | Brokerage | Broker   |
+----+--------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: @ypercube see my comment below to Gordon, cheers, Welly

Comment: Comments usually are not as clear as an actual output. Please edit the question.

Comment: Sorry good point @ypercube I've edited the question, sample required output at the bottom.

Comment: Still the data don't match. How the `job_type=39` is related to (and produces) the `Brokerage` and `Broker`?

Comment: Sorry @ypercube refreshed the table with the wrong number, it should have been id=80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need 2 `LEFT` joins but the other way around:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       js.name AS job_sector, 
       jt.name AS job_type,
       c.job_name  
FROM client_skills_new AS c
  LEFT JOIN job_sectors AS js
    ON c.job_sector = js.id
  LEFT JOIN job_sectors AS jt
    ON c.job_type = jt.id
WHERE c.client_id='$client_id' ;
```

Comment: Brilliant works perfectly, I thought I might have been doing a second join the wrong way round!

Comment: And you only need LEFT joins if the `job_sector` and `job_type` columns are nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `where` clause.  It is "undoing" the `left outer join`, because the values in one table are NULL when there is no match.

The fix is to move the logic to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT client_skills_new.job_sector, job_sectors.id, job_sectors.name
FROM job_sectors LEFT JOIN
     client_skills_new
     ON client_skills_new.job_sector = job_sectors.id and
        client_id='$client_id';
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, I've probably not phrased the question very well. The output I'm looking for is basically as four columns: id, job_sector, job_type and job_name, so similar to my client_skills_new table except I want the numerical values of job_type and job_name to be substituted for the text that represents them in job_sectors